# Using substr + SUBSTR MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have an string:

```
Result":{"CreateDate":"2021-05-27T19:58:33","OrderKey":"6ea1eb40-bd80-4e8b-8e78-a7 ","OrderReference":"app_iheillyy_9816617_AF_e2002"}}
```

and then
I need to extract the position after `"OrderKey"` with some positions

and than will be this:
`OrderKey":"6ea1eb40-bd80-4e8b-8e78-a7 "`,

its possible with two or more functions ?

Answer (score 1):

Your string is nearly a JSON value provided a little string `{"` is prepended to it. Then, you'll be able to use `JSON_EXTRACT()` function in order to get the expected key-value pair such as

```sql
SELECT CONCAT('"OrderKey":',
              JSON_EXTRACT(CONCAT('{"',str),"$.Result.OrderKey")
              ) AS key_value
  FROM t;

key_value
----------------------------------------
"OrderKey":"6ea1eb40-bd80-4e8b-8e78-a7 "
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=03585bb7502906bb479d5ec2bb0d8bde)</kbd>

Comment: your way is much better. vote up

Answer (score 0):

you can use **SUBSTRING_INDEX** and **CONCAT** like this:

```
SET @mystr := 'Result":{"CreateDate":"2021-05-27T19:58:33","OrderKey":"6ea1eb40-bd80-4e8b-8e78-a7 ","OrderReference":"app_iheillyy_9816617_AF_e2002"}}"';

SELECT
CONCAT('"OrderKey',
SUBSTRING_INDEX(
SUBSTRING_INDEX(@mystr, "OrderKey", -1), ",", 1)) ;
```

**sample**

```
MariaDB [bernd]> SET @mystr := 'Result":{"CreateDate":"2021-05-27T19:58:33","OrderKey":"6ea1eb40-bd80-4e8b-8e78-a7 ","OrderReference":"app_iheillyy_9816617_AF_e2002"}}"';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [bernd]> 
MariaDB [bernd]> SELECT
    -> CONCAT('"OrderKey',
    -> SUBSTRING_INDEX(
    -> SUBSTRING_INDEX(@mystr, "OrderKey", -1), ",", 1)) ;
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| CONCAT('"OrderKey',
SUBSTRING_INDEX(
SUBSTRING_INDEX(@mystr, "OrderKey", -1), ",", 1)) |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| "OrderKey":"6ea1eb40-bd80-4e8b-8e78-a7 "                                               |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [bernd]>
```

Comment: work's for me this way
select JSON_EXTRACT(t.response_json,"$.OrderResult.OrderKey"),t.id,  t.order_id